# Why is my cin getting errors when having 80+ lines of input?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

**EDIT**
Sorry I forgot to add the i++; However that was not the problem. The problem was that **cin stop getting input after 80+ lines**. Since I used cout to directly see if cin is successful, I could keep a track on how my cin performing.

This is my first time asking a serious question... However this problem is so weird to me and I have to ask for help.

So the program is basically getting input and output what was entered. This process will repeat 100 times and I don't know why, it always jam at about 89 line.

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    while (i<100){
        long long key;
        cin >> key;
        cout << key<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

And the input I use is like this:

```
40279559
 774613289
 869592654
 165280355
 776346290
 221187096
 421986249
 83228103
 640319482
 528689193
 75245219
 617070033
 66257759
 25751289
 282482494
 954357244
 477444954
 608389416
 400483980
 477444954
 441393551
 66257759
 822218158
 806479414
 548665149
 66257759
 234121006
 663305907
 314809050
 0
 487458874
 66257759
 918193520
 606474691
 188185089
 322445571
 66257759
 814123984
 0
 0
 689260392
 204276815
 66257759
 488766408
 412617563
 463415495
 601030115
 776513589
 257003372
 154047223
 154047223
 219327735
 978812473
 978817223
 718062555
 128066784
 15718305
 754978417
 643892549
 192401474
 643892549
 638898307
 973173529
 506709268
 506709268
 744166533
 638898307
 9524075
 997348833
 31190791
 21011834
 217208615
 401912531
 0
 251082460
 542593404
 702430665
 48285749
 831077135
 917941607
 908494561
 671239874
 333354822
 261522346
 170201520
 139162050
 677374727
 992422786
 500171144
 239436034
 556867643
 992422786
 720003678
 220110584
 31190791
 898610232
 682670734
 547596765
 496810115
 41728941
```

Please help me for this problem. I have tried many hours and still have no idea.

Thank you very much!

David

Comment: You need to post the actual code that produces the error. Is your data corrupt?

Comment: This is the actual code. I open a new file just to test this part and this problem still exists. the input data should be fine I think.

Comment: I tried your code in Visual Studio with your sample data and it worked fine. Possibly your data file has a EOF marker in it. Can you try it with another file (just cut and paste from this page).

Comment: The code you posted here works fine for me too with the data you posted. I recommend checking for errors after you read in each number.

Comment: It works correctly on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ueCGT1)

Comment: What do you mean you open a new input file? This program reads from the console. How exactly are you providing the input?

Answer (score 1):

Since you forgot to increment `i`. This program will fall into infinite loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i<100){
    // Do something
    i++; // Increment i to get rid of infinite loop.
}
```

As  pointed out by AndyG in comment section. You can use for loop too.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: Or maybe use a for loop

Comment: That wasn't solving my question. My problem was that my cin stop getting data from input after dealing with 80+ lines. I have no idea why is that

Comment: Have you tried fewer lines? Once I had a problem where my `cin` couldn't get more than 100 chars.

Comment: I have to go with this many lines of input. If the number of lines lower than 80, it will surely pass.